# Endless 101 Switching Protocols requests

Tags: reactjs, express, ws

I have simple react app, and express backend with rest api.
I am making request from employees component to backend, and i'm getting data (from mongodb), but in chrome dev tools i see endless ws requests. How can i avoid it?

[chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFDuj.jpg)

[useAxios hook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS4Hv.png)

[Employees comp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFVkV.png)

[employees controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr52Y.png)

[employees router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dqsxh.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: done, via screens